# Receive note events from a MIDI file with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, midi

In JavaScript, what is a good way to receive an event for every note played in a MIDI file?

I've tried using MIDI.js with something like:

```
MIDI.loadPlugin(function() {

  player = MIDI.Player;
  player.loadFile( song[songid], player.start );

  player.addListener( midiNotePlayedCallback );

  MIDI.loader.stop();
});
```

But it insists on loading a SoundFont, which I don't need (and in this case fails on an XHR request) - I'm just looking for the note events to work with.

Comment: That's interesting. I don't know nothing about this, but I'll have a look! I used to do music production : )

Comment: If you could share a jsbin or jsfiddler would be even better!

Comment: I would be glad to share a jsbin or jsfiddler, but am not sure how to include the MIDI.js library there.  Otherwise I'm open to using any other library that enables me to register a callback for each note in the midi file, as MIDI.Player.addListener(...) in the MIDI.js library seems to do.  So far I've based my experiments on this:  https://github.com/mudcube/MIDI.js/blob/master/demo-MIDIPlayer.html

Comment: You can find it at www.cdnjs.com and add it on the header of jsbin html document. example http://jsbin.com/dohupi/1